# Can i restart an app once it becomes active again?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have an app that stores data in a coredata db. I save data to the db from a web service when the app is started. The thing is that people can keep their app in the background even for weeks and may see data that is no longer valid. I would like to kind of reinitialize the entire app once it comes from background (a sort of restart, if you will) because i have multiple tabs. Can this be done?

Comment: sure, you can check validity of your data in your app delegate, e.g. in `- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application` it is not possible to force app to restart; even if it would it for sure violates apple's HIG

Comment: yeah, i sent my comment by accident sooner - see my edit. It is not allowed to force close your app - because apple thinks it looks like a crash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to restart the app each time it enters foreground. You can disable "multitasking" by adding this to your project's `info.plist`

Add a new row and select “Application does not run in background” (or type “UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend”) and then toggle the checkbox.

**EDIT:** (Thanks to [Kevin Ballard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/582/kevin-ballard)) It's better if you check if it's been a long time since the last time it downloaded the data and, in that case, re-download the data. You should only disable "multitasking" when you have a really good reason to do that. This is not that case.

Comment: For the record, you should only do this if you have a really good reason why you shouldn't support multitasking. I suspect the OP would be far better served just making his app re-download the data and re-save to the db if it's been long enough since the last time.

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't you just refresh the UI? Core Data has plenty of notifications for keeping up with the changes in the context, for example `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification` which has all the updates/deletes/inserts with it as well. Just start observing it before you update the DB and you'll see if any changes occur.

No need to restart to reload the UI, all the callbacks are there...

So instead of updating your data in `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` do it in `applicationDidBecomeActive:` and use Core Data notifications to update the UI as necessary.